# Relationship between SVD of Matrix and SVD of same Matrix with deleted entries (Matrix can be Adjacency Matrix of a Graph)

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Could somebody direct to me to some literature dealing with this issue. So we have $X = U\Sigma V^{T}$ and we have $M \odot X = U^{'}\Sigma^{'}V^{'^{T}}$ with
\begin{equation}
M_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{or} \\
    0           
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
X and M can be symmetric and X could be a Graph (so: how does the spectral decomposition change if i delete a vertice)
I know general perturbation bounds or bounds using the fact that $M$ is a Matrix with Random entries. My Question is if there is an exact relationship like a formula with an equality relating these two quantities (their singular vectors and/or their singular values). Maybe this is related to like an entrywise updated calculation of an SVD for example. If there are perturbation bounds specifically for graphs then if somebody could mention them that would b helpful too! Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have a very particular structure of $X$ and $M$ in mind, it's difficult to see how to make any progress with the SVD here.  Generically, removing even a single coefficient in $X$ can enormously change $U$, $V,$ and $\Sigma.$

Comment: M could be symmetric and X could be symmetric. X could also be the adjacency matrix of a graph. I will add that to the question.

Comment: Consider the SVD of the graph laplacian matrix $L$. The multiplicity of 0 singular values of $L$ equals the number of connected components of the graph. If you delete some well-chosen edges, you could increase the number of connected components of the graph, causing the multiplicity of 0 singular values to be larger. Is this what you want to know? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: If $A$ is a symmetric matrix of order $n$ with eigenvalues $a_1\leq a_2\leq \ldots\leq a_n$ and if $M=\left[\begin{array}{cc}A&b^T\\b&c\end{array}\right]$ with $b\in R^n$ and $c\in R$ has eigenvalues $m_0\leq m_1\leq \ldots\leq m_n$  then a classical theorem of linear algebra says that $$m_0\leq a_1\leq m_1\leq a_2\leq m_2\leq \ldots\leq a_n\leq m_n.$$